# net_rim_crypto error in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, installation

I'm developing a blackberry application to encode and decode some important information. For this I'm using the net.rim.device.api.crypto.* package in my application. I'm developing in blackberry OS 7.1 simulator but my blackberry device has OS 5.0 .  When I try to download the app in my device, it gives me the following error:

> "This application requires the following module, which is not installed: net_rim_crypto"

Also I'm not able to use the update site and install previous blackberry Os versions as the installation fails whenever I try to install it.

So, my question is mainly: How can I make my apps backward compatible in this case? Also, I'm not able to install and run my app (mentioned above) on the device. How can I accomplish this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that BlackBerry apps are not backward compatible, that is to say an app built on OS 7.0 will not work with OS 6.0 or OS 5.0. However, an same app built on OS 5.0 will work on handsets with OS 5.0+. Considering you are developing your app in OS 7.1 simulator indicates you are using BlackBerry JRE 7 and net_rim_crypto that you implemented seem to be missing in OS 5. In order to develop apps for OS 5, please work with JRE 5.

Comment: Thanks for the expalination Sarah. Actually, as I mentioned in my post, I'm not able to install previous OS versions in my Eclipse. Currently I have OS 7 in the Eclipse I'm working on and I have OS 5.0 on the device. Can you please suggest me a method? Also, I want my apps built on lower OS versions so that any user of higher OS version can use it. How can I do it with the problem I shared with you? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend posting this as a new question because this is different from what was asked above (SO question asking policies). However, in order to use another JRE version, in the BuildPath, double click on JRE System Library. You should see a dropdown box with all installed components. You can look in Installed JRE - see if it is installed. If you can't see the JRE, take a look in Eclipse install folder under Plugin/net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.6.0/components for a BlackBerry.ee file. You can manually add the component by selecting this file - Add in the Installed JRE window

Comment: Both my questions are linked that's why I have posted them together. I'm getting the net_rim_crypto error on my because of OS conflict in my simulator and device. I've new OS version on Eclipse,I have to install previous versions of Blackberry OS and then add net_rim_crypto component(which also I can't seem to find anywhere) and then sign & package my application. I'm not able to install previous OS versions on my Eclipse. I have clicked Help> Install New Software and used the Update Site (http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java),still not able to install it. Somebody please help.